# MIDIPacketList send with quantized MIDITimeStamp

Tags: ios, coremidi

Have some troubles with CoreMIDI. I'm looking to send few quantized midi messages in one MIDIPacketList using different timestamps. Here's my code

```
MIDITimeStamp triggerHostTime = gridModel->gridRows[rowIndex]->framesPerTrigger * PB_AUDIO_FRAMES_TO_HOSTTICK_FACTOR;

Byte note = PB_MIDI_NOTES[rowIndex];

MIDIPacketList *packetList = (MIDIPacketList *)malloc(PB_MIDI_PACKETLIST_SIZE);
MIDIPacket *curPacket  = MIDIPacketListInit(packetList);
MIDITimeStamp packetHostTime = mach_absolute_time();

Byte off_message[3] = {MIDI_NOTE_OFF, note, 0};

for (int i = 0; i < item->trigger; i++) {
    Byte on_message[3] = {MIDI_NOTE_ON, note, 127};
    curPacket = MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, PB_MIDI_PACKETLIST_SIZE, curPacket,
                                  packetHostTime,
                                  3, on_message);

    packetHostTime += triggerHostTime;
    curPacket = MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, PB_MIDI_PACKETLIST_SIZE, curPacket,
                                  packetHostTime - 1e6 * PB_AUDIO_NS_TO_HOSTTICK_FACTOR,
                                  3, off_message);

}

pb_midi_manager_send_packet_list(packetList);

free(packetList);
```

*framesPerTrigger* is length of quantization in audio frames. for example I have *framesPerTrigger = 22050*, so I need quantization with 0.5 sec. *item->trigger* is count of notes prepared to send. I'm adding packet with note_on message, then calculate next timestamp and adding note_off 1ms earlier. *PB_MIDI_PACKETLIST_SIZE = 512*

Sending function:

```
void pb_midi_manager_send_packet_list(MIDIPacketList* packetList) {

    for (ItemCount index = 0; index < MIDIGetNumberOfDestinations(); ++index) {
    MIDIEndpointRef MIDIEndpoint = MIDIGetDestination(index);
    if (MIDIEndpoint) {
        MIDISend(MIDIOutput, MIDIEndpoint, packetList);
        }
    }
}
```

I've read about converting between host time ticks and real time in nanoseconds, so:

```
mach_timebase_info_data_t tinfo;
mach_timebase_info(&tinfo);

PB_AUDIO_HOSTTICK_TO_NS_FACTOR = ((double)tinfo.numer / tinfo.denom);
PB_AUDIO_NS_TO_HOSTTICK_FACTOR = 1.0 / PB_AUDIO_HOSTTICK_TO_NS_FACTOR;

PB_AUDIO_FRAMES_TO_HOSTTICK_FACTOR = 1e9 * PB_AUDIO_NS_TO_HOSTTICK_FACTOR / PB_AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE;
```

In MIDIMonitor everything looks good:

[MIDI Monitor log](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/102794260727750654036/albums/6074309082109312737/6074309093037958050?pid=6074309093037958050&oid=102794260727750654036)

but in the DAW (Ableton) I'm receiving only one very short note. is it possible that DAW cannot unpack midi notes from packetlist? I think no.. so where is my problem? Is there other way to schedule output midi notes? I've tried to set timestamps directly to *curPacket->timeStamp* and get few notes received but with horrible delay and swapping of note_on and note_off messages.

I'm working with iOS simulator and use network midi connection.

Thank you for attention and possible answers!

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this problem? I have a similar issue as well.